# Analyse time based data and get distribution of data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distribution

I would like to analyse the historic data to get the distribution of the data.

The data from tData table is 15 minute based, it has over 10 billion records, which makes performance really critical. I would like to analyze all 96 points (1 day = 96 * 15 minutes) across all years of data.

For example, for "00:15", I will get the minimum and maximum across all the data that is "00:15", let's say:

```
2010-01-01 00:15
2010-01-02 00:15
2010-01-03 00:15
2010-01-04 00:15
2010-01-05 00:15
2010-01-06 00:15
2010-01-07 00:15
...
...
```

Then I will use the following query to get the distribution of the data in 10 sections from tData table (DeviceID + FooTime is PK), and tData is a physical table but here just for test sample:

```
declare @tData table(DeviceID nvarchar(10), FooTime datetime, Value float)

--just dummy data, actual data will have full 96 points for each day
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-01 00:15', 3)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-02 00:15', 4)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-03 00:15', 5)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-04 00:15', 2)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-05 00:15', 3)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-06 00:15', 4)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-07 00:15', 5)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-08 00:15', 6)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-09 00:15', 7)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-10 00:15', 11)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-11 00:15', 12)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-12 00:15', 13)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-13 00:15', 14)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-14 00:15', 15)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-15 00:15', 16)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-16 00:15', 17)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-17 00:15', 18)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-18 00:15', 10)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-19 00:15', 19)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-20 00:15', 9)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-21 00:15', 8)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-22 00:15', 3)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-23 00:15', 4)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-24 00:15', 4)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-25 00:15', 2)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-26 00:15', 2)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-27 00:15', 5)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-28 00:15', 6)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-29 00:15', 2)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-30 00:15', 14)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-31 00:15', 15)
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-02-01 00:15', 25)

DECLARE @CurrentPoint nvarchar(10) 
DECLARE @MinValue float 
DECLARE @MaxValue float 
DECLARE @AvgValue float 
DECLARE @StartDate datetime 
DECLARE @EndDate datetime 
DECLARE @RangeWidth float 
DECLARE @RangeCount float 

SET @StartDate = '2010-01-01' 
SET @EndDate = '2010-02-02' 
SET @CurrentPoint = '00:15' 
SET @RangeCount = 9 

SELECT @MinValue = MIN(Value), @MaxValue = MAX(Value), @AvgValue = AVG(Value) 
    FROM @tData  
    WHERE DeviceID = 'PM00100' AND FooTime between @StartDate and @EndDate AND CONVERT(nvarchar(5), FooTime, 108) = @CurrentPoint 

SET @RangeWidth = (@MaxValue - @MinValue) / @RangeCount 

SELECT FLOOR((Value - @MinValue)/@RangeWidth) * @RangeWidth + @MinValue as LowerBound 
    ,FLOOR((Value - @MinValue)/@RangeWidth) * @RangeWidth + @MinValue + @RangeWidth as UpperBound 
    ,COUNT(*) AS Count 
    ,FLOOR((Value - @MinValue)/@RangeWidth) AS Position 
    FROM @tData  
    WHERE DeviceID = 'PM00100' AND FooTime between @StartDate and @EndDate AND CONVERT(nvarchar(5), FooTime, 108) = @CurrentPoint 
    GROUP BY FLOOR((Value - @MinValue) / @RangeWidth)
```

the above mentioned query get the difference between maximum and minimum values, and divide by 9 (turn out to be 10 sections), for each range of data I would like to get how many records belongs to that range. The position is simply outputing the index.

The query works fine for one 15 minute point of data, but when I want to do all 96 points (daily, from 00:00 to 23:45), right now I am using a loop, it's very slow. I believe it is because I do not need to do 96 queries, I could do it in one shot, but I could not figure it out.

the result will look like:

```
LowerBound       UpperBound         Count Position
2.00000000000000 4.55555555555556   11    0
4.55555555555556 7.11111111111111   6     1
7.11111111111111 9.66666666666667   2     2
9.66666666666667 12.2222222222222   3     3
12.2222222222222 14.7777777777778   3     4
14.7777777777778 17.3333333333333   4     5
17.3333333333333 19.8888888888889   2     6
25.0000000000000 27.5555555555556   1     9
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using (always good to specify)? If 2008+, have you considered using a TIME column to separate that logic? How about replicating older data into an archive table, perhaps on a readonly filegroup or another server altogether, so that your reporting / analysis aren't subject to blocking or other performance issues from the primary function of the app...

Comment: Hi, we are using SQL Server 2005, and our data have to use datetime, but for processing purpose in a temporary table, we might be able to use nchar(5) etc. We already use table partitioning, and normal query is good. The main problem here is for existing data (could not change table structure), how to have a better peformance

Comment: I think you need to clean up your sample data and describe how you got the results above. (1) your dates don't match (2) your devices don't match (3) when I build a table with your sample data and run your query, I get a divide by zero error. I've given you a start in my answer only because it wouldn't make sense as a comment. If you provide clearer specs you will find folks will be able to give you a much clearer answer.

Comment: Hi, I jsut updated my question with a fully working and correct sample code and result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to improve the performance by doing the query in one shot, rather than iterating all the time points. It first the the min/max for each point and store them in temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE #ProfiledData(ID int identity(1,1), TimePoint nchar(5), MinValue float NULL, MaxValue float NULL, RangeWidth float NULL)
DECLARE @RangeCount float   
SET @RangeCount = 9
declare @tData table(DeviceID nvarchar(10), FooTime datetime, Value float)
--just dummy data, actual data will have full 96 points for each day  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-01 00:00', 3)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-02 00:00', 4)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-03 00:00', 5)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-04 00:00', 2)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-05 00:00', 3)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-06 00:00', 4)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-07 00:00', 5)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-08 00:00', 6)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-09 00:00', 7)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-10 00:00', 11)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-11 00:00', 12)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-12 00:00', 13)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-13 00:00', 14)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-14 00:00', 15)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-15 00:00', 16)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-16 00:00', 17)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-17 00:00', 18)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-18 00:00', 10)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-19 00:00', 19)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-20 00:00', 9)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-21 00:00', 8)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-22 00:00', 3)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-23 00:00', 4)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-24 00:00', 4)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-25 00:00', 2)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-26 00:00', 2)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-27 00:00', 5)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-28 00:00', 6)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-29 00:00', 2)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-30 00:00', 14)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-31 00:00', 15)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-02-01 00:00', 25)  

INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-01 00:15', 3)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-02 00:15', 4)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-03 00:15', 5)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-04 00:15', 2)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-05 00:15', 3)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-06 00:15', 4)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-07 00:15', 5)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-08 00:15', 6)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-09 00:15', 7)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-10 00:15', 11)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-11 00:15', 12)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-12 00:15', 13)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-13 00:15', 14)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-14 00:15', 15)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-15 00:15', 16)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-16 00:15', 17)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-17 00:15', 18)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-18 00:15', 10)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-19 00:15', 19)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-20 00:15', 9)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-21 00:15', 8)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-22 00:15', 3)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-23 00:15', 4)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-24 00:15', 4)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-25 00:15', 2)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-26 00:15', 2)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-27 00:15', 5)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-28 00:15', 6)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-29 00:15', 2)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-30 00:15', 14)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-01-31 00:15', 15)  
INSERT INTO @tData VALUES ('PM00100', '2010-02-01 00:15', 25)  

INSERT INTO #ProfiledData (TimePoint) VALUES ('00:00')
INSERT INTO #ProfiledData (TimePoint) VALUES ('00:15')
--...
--...

UPDATE #ProfiledData SET MinValue = m.MinValue, MaxValue = m.MaxValue, RangeWidth = (m.MaxValue - m.MinValue) / @RangeCount
    FROM (SELECT CONVERT(nchar(5), FooTime, 108) AS TimePoint, MIN(Value) AS MinValue, MAX(Value) AS MaxValue
        FROM @tData
        GROUP BY CONVERT(nchar(5), FooTime, 108)) m
    LEFT JOIN #ProfiledData a ON a.TimePoint = m.TimePoint

SELECT a.TimePoint
    ,FLOOR((Value - MinValue)/ RangeWidth) * RangeWidth + MinValue as LowerBound
    ,FLOOR((Value - MinValue)/ RangeWidth) * RangeWidth + RangeWidth + MinValue as UpperBound
    ,COUNT(*) AS Total
    ,FLOOR((Value - MinValue)/ RangeWidth) AS Position
    FROM @tData d
        INNER JOIN #ProfiledData a ON a.TimePoint = CONVERT(nchar(5), d.FooTime, 108)
    WHERE d.DeviceID = 'PM00100'
    GROUP BY a.TimePoint, RangeWidth, MinValue, FLOOR((Value - MinValue) / RangeWidth)

DROP TABLE #ProfiledData
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I follow the other calculations, why you need to take AVG/MAX etc. first, what RangeCount and RangeWidth mean, and so on, but maybe this will give you a start:

```
;WITH cte(t,v) AS 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5), FooTime, 108), [Value]
      FROM @tData
      WHERE FooTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
)
SELECT t,MIN(v),MAX(v),AVG(v) FROM cte GROUP BY t;
```

This will give you a row for each time slice. You can nest more CTEs for further calculations with the aggregates. I couldn't make heads or tails of the calculations you were doing, and it seemed like your sample data and desired results don't quite match up.

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not explain clearly, and I am sorry I did not gave actual result, I just put dummy data. I updated my original question, hopefully you maybe have a better understanding about my question.

Comment: Is there any one that could help me?

Comment: Can you please define a "section"? How do I determine what section a row belongs to?